# "Unable to alter partition" in Hive from Spark app

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hive

I have a Spark application with which I read JSON records into a `DataFrame`, transform the data (i.e. flatten it for use in a BI tool), and then insert it into an existing partitioned Hive table. The `DataFrame` only contains data from the same partition columns, say `x` and `y` and the `PARTITION` clause only has these static values, so there is no `ALTER TABLE` command going on. The code to achieve that looks like this:

```
df.registerTempTable("tempTab")
hc.sql(s"USE $schema")
hc.sql(
  s"""INSERT INTO TABLE $table PARTITION (x="$x", y="$y")
      | SELECT * FROM tempTab""".stripMargin)
```

The problem is: when I run the app it inserts a few hundred MBs worth of data and then gives me:

```
ERROR metadata.Hive: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to alter partition.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getPartition(Hive.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartition(Hive.java:1256)
```

The thing is, I'm not altering a partition, I'm inserting into it. *And* the first chunk of records from the *same* `DataFrame` are actually inserted into Hive (I checked).

The error appears to be caused by:

```
Caused by: MetaException(message:java.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE, inode="/apps/hive/warehouse/demo.db/demotable/x=foo/y=bar":dude:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
```

We use MySQL as a metastore and user impersonation in Spark. I know that user impersonation is not passed on to Hive from within Spark but the `hive` user has `rwx` access through ACLs. I checked with `hdfs dfs -getfacl /apps/hive/warehouse/demo.db` and the group that `hive` belongs to has all permissions.

However, near the top of the log I see the following:

```
spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn, dude); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn, dude)
```

This seems to indicate to me that the ACLs are disabled and only basic permissions are used. What worries me is that a good portion of the data is inserted into Hive, so that a permissions problem seems very unlikely IMHO. I don't think there is a job in the background that resets permissions or something weird like that.

I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947341/hive-cannot-alter-table-error) where a simple `LOAD` statement caused the same 'Unable to alter partition' exception and it might have been caused by MySQL as the metastore. [This post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-dev/201406.mbox/%3CCAORpBsgz83Zpz8EGYqAmsPu8y1DzfpTBsPkGL66aPhy=iRSQXA@mail.gmail.com%3E) describes the possibility of a too high load on the metastore.

Edit: I just created the partition from within Hive and the permissions are different from the ones created by Spark. Is there a way to make Spark play nicely?

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out the problem:

- When Spark creates partitions it creates these using user permissions, so in my case for the user `dude` and the group `hdfs`. Interestingly, neither `hive` nor `spark` are users in the group `hdfs`; `dude` is also *not* part of that group. For some reason the group that `hive` and `spark` belong to is called `hadoop` on our cluster. Anyway, that means `hive` cannot insert because by default the ACLs are ignored (more on that later). I'm guessing Spark unloads the data in batches and after the first batch that causes a problem because of the basic permissions.
- I can create the partitions directly in Hive, which then uses the default permissions of the directories. That at least solves the problem, but ideally I'd use Spark to create them on the fly if needed.
- To that end, I had to set the parameter `spark.acls.enable=true`, in which case it used the ACLs and since the `hadoop` group is allowed to read/write/execute, all's well.

Comment: Have you tried to make hive and spark as proxy users? I think it is more decent way to solve the problem

Comment: Do you mean the `proxy-user` parameter of `spark-submit`? That would impersonate those users, right? I'm quite sure that `hive` does not have access to the raw JSON documents...

Comment: No, the proxy user for hadoop, in core-site.xml. this will allow hive to impersonate the users who issued the commands (dude)  instead of  executing as hive